# FreeBSD pf firewall, new connections severly delayed when nating

Tags: freebsd, firewall, pf, nat

I have a newly setup fbsd 9.1 with pf, which itself doesn't experience any slowness when for example downloading a debian iso from my local debian repo (ftp.se.debian.org). Any machine behind it, which the freebsd firewall routes and nats for, experiences about 10-12 seconds before getting any data back after the initial tcp handshake is formed.

Speed after the initial delay is fine, about 10-12 MB/s constantly. I suspect I am doing something wrong, see rules and tcpdump below. It might be worth adding that freebsd is running in a XenServer (6.0) VM, with the xenhvm devices compiled in a custom kernel.

```
# pf.conf
wanif = "xn0"
dmzif = "xn2"
dmznet  = "10.64.1.0/24"

scrub on $wanif reassemble tcp no-df random-id

nat on $wanif from $dmzif:network to any -> ($wanif)

block log
block in all
pass quick on lo0 all
pass out all keep state

pass in quick on $dmzif inet from $dmznet to ! $intnets keep state

pass out on $wanif proto tcp all modulate state flags S/SA
pass out on $wanif all keep state




    # tcpdump -ni xn0

    12:09:04.389635 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [S], seq 2077316563, win 5840, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 478788359 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
    12:09:04.401362 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 71.72.73.74.51953: Flags [S.], seq 93082952, ack 2077316564, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2817201177 ecr 478788359,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    12:09:04.401851 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478788362 ecr 2817201177], length 0
    12:09:04.402126 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478788362 ecr 2817201177], length 194
    12:09:04.611851 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478788415 ecr 2817201177], length 194
    12:09:05.035855 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478788521 ecr 2817201177], length 194
    12:09:05.884041 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478788733 ecr 2817201177], length 194
    12:09:07.580009 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478789157 ecr 2817201177], length 194
    12:09:07.944140 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 71.72.73.74.51953: Flags [S.], seq 93082952, ack 2077316564, win 5792, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 2817204720 ecr 478788362,nop,wscale 7], length 0
    12:09:07.944908 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478789248 ecr 2817204720,nop,nop,sack 1 {0:1}], length 0
    12:09:10.972026 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478790005 ecr 2817204720], length 194
    12:09:17.756060 IP 71.72.73.74.51953 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 1:195, ack 1, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 478791701 ecr 2817204720], length 194
    12:09:17.767744 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 71.72.73.74.51953: Flags [.], ack 195, win 54, options [nop,nop,TS val 2817214544 ecr 478791701], length 0
    12:09:17.895263 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 71.72.73.74.51953: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 195, win 54, options [nop,nop,TS val 2817214672 ecr 478791701], length 1448
    12:09:17.895326 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 71.72.73.74.51953: Flags [.], seq 1449:2897, ack 195, win 54, options [nop,nop,TS val 2817214672 ecr 478791701], length 1448

    # tcpdump -ni xn2 port 80
    tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
    listening on xn2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
    12:03:18.248115 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [P.], seq 827084948:827085121, ack 856345816, win 365, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916027 ecr 3651988161], length 173
    12:03:18.269060 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991631 ecr 4294916027], length 0 
    12:03:18.269309 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 1:1449, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991631 ecr 4294916027], length 1448
    12:03:18.269364 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 1449:2897, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991631 ecr 4294916027], length 1448
    12:03:18.269397 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 2897:4345, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991631 ecr 4294916027], length 1448
    12:03:18.269427 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [P.], seq 4345:5793, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991631 ecr 4294916027], length 1448
    12:03:18.269744 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 1449, win 546, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916032 ecr 3651991631], length 0 
    12:03:18.269797 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 2897, win 727, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916032 ecr 3651991631], length 0 
    12:03:18.269818 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 4345, win 908, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916032 ecr 3651991631], length 0 
    12:03:18.269837 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 5793, win 1089, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916032 ecr 3651991631], length 0 
    12:03:18.269861 IP 10.64.1.2.53888 > 130.239.18.173.80: Flags [F.], seq 1457436047, ack 1959872378, win 452, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916032 ecr 1986976335], length 0
    12:03:18.290194 IP 130.239.18.173.80 > 10.64.1.2.53888: Flags [.], ack 1, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 1986977333 ecr 4294916032], length 0
    12:03:18.290227 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 5793:7241, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290247 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 7241:8689, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290266 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 8689:10137, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290292 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [P.], seq 10137:11585, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290312 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 11585:13033, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290332 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 13033:14481, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290357 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 14481:15929, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290382 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [P.], seq 15929:17377, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290420 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 17377:18825, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290444 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 18825:20273, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290469 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 20273:21721, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991637 ecr 4294916032], length 1448
    12:03:18.290553 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 7241, win 1270, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290599 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 8689, win 1451, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290621 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 10137, win 1632, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290640 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 11585, win 1813, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290665 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 13033, win 1994, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290684 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 14481, win 2175, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290705 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 15929, win 2356, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290729 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 17377, win 2537, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290755 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 18825, win 2718, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290774 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 20273, win 2899, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.290798 IP 10.64.1.2.34774 > 194.71.11.69.80: Flags [.], ack 21721, win 3080, options [nop,nop,TS val 4294916037 ecr 3651991637], length 0 
    12:03:18.311156 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 21721:23169, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991642 ecr 4294916037], length 1448
    12:03:18.311190 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 23169:24617, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991642 ecr 4294916037], length 1448
    12:03:18.311208 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 24617:26065, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991642 ecr 4294916037], length 1448
    12:03:18.311228 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 26065:27513, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991642 ecr 4294916037], length 1448
    12:03:18.311247 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [.], seq 27513:28961, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991642 ecr 4294916037], length 1448
    12:03:18.311266 IP 194.71.11.69.80 > 10.64.1.2.34774: Flags [P.], seq 28961:30409, ack 173, win 122, options [nop,nop,TS val 3651991642 ecr 4294916037], length 1448
```

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of FreeBSD/pf were known to have issues with the Xen driver and TCP Segmentation Offloading.

Try: sysctl net.inet.tcp.tso=0